# How to push a command to the function parameters from the command line arguments?

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, scripting

I want to write a function that runs a given command and outputs a given message if there are errors when running this command. Command and message are passed to the function as an arguments.

Actually, this small script is for the project "A Continuous Integration System" from the series "50 Lines or Less". Here in a project description, all shell scripts are written in bash but i have Windows and i want rewrite all shell scripts on powershell, for some practice.

This is code that i have now:

```
function rof{
    param(
        [string] $msg,
        [scriptblock] $cmd
    )
    try {
        Invoke-Command $cmd
    }
    catch {
        $msg
    }
}
```

I expected that when i run this function like

```
rof -msg "some error :(" -cmd {git log}
```

that command in {} will be invoked or "some error" will outputs if, for example there are no git repository.
But function outputs

```
git log
```

What am i doing wrong? I've never written in powershell before. Help me please. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Treat PowerShell as just another shell, you don't need to use Invoke-Command to call a command. Just call it as is, since you have to pass the arguments of the command, using Invoke-Expression will be the best option here.

```
function rof{
    param(
        [string] $msg,
        [string] $cmd
    )
    try {
        Invoke-Expression $cmd
    }
    catch {
        $msg
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But output still the same.

Answer (score 0):

The scriptblock was successfully invoked from PowerShell's point of view, meaning there is no terminating error which triggers the `catch`. What you can do instead is checking the `$LASTEXITCODE` variable, which will contain the exit code from your external command.

```
    function rof {
    param(
            [string] $msg,
            [scriptblock] $cmd
    )

            & $cmd

            if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
                    $msg
                    $LASTEXITCODE
            }

    }
```

Example:

```
    rof -msg "test" -cmd {cmd.exe /c exit 123}
    test
    123
```

However, let me add that this proxy function sounds like a bad idea. I don't know your exact use-case, but this will just invoke anything (very unsecure in a constrained PowerShell) and always returns a message that is defined by the caller. But how would the caller know, what the error might be...?